# native vim plugin load order

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Sometimes Vim plugins suggest a load order, but Vim nowaday natively supports loading plugins with no plugin manager. You just put a submodule in a folder such as `~/.vim/pack/vendor/start` and it'll automatically load. So, my question is how do you ensure a load order similar to how people would previously. Older way of doing things example below:

```
Plug 'preservim/nerdtree' |
            \ Plug 'Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin' |
            \ Plug 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons'
```

Taken from https://github.com/Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin#faq.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try a little experiment…

1. Create the following dummy files with their corresponding content:

   | Filepath | Content |
   | --- | --- |
   | `pack/dummy/start/nerdtree/plugin/foo.vim` | `echom "nerdtree"` |
   | `pack/dummy/start/nerdtree-git-plugin/plugin/bar.vim` | `echom "nerdtree-git-plugin"` |
   | `pack/dummy/start/vim-devicons/plugin/baz.vim` | `echom "vim-devicons"` |
2. Start Vim and you should see something like the following:

   ```
   $ vim
   nerdtree
   nerdtree-git-plugin
   vim-devicons
   Press ENTER or type command to continue
   ```

   which is consistant with:

   ```
   :filter dummy scriptnames
    40: ~/.vim/pack/dummy/start/nerdtree/plugin/foo.vim
    41: ~/.vim/pack/dummy/start/nerdtree-git-plugin/plugin/bar.vim
    42: ~/.vim/pack/dummy/start/vim-devicons/plugin/baz.vim
   Press ENTER or type command to continue
   ```

Based on this experiment, we can conclude that the built-in "package" feature will "load" plugins found in `start/` in the filesystem order which happens to be the same as the prescribed order anyway. Of course, *your* filesystem may order directories differently than mine, so YMMV.

In theory, the `:help :packadd` command should allow you to "manage" your plugins from your `vimrc`, like you would with a plugin manager. Let's experiment with it…

1. Rename `start/` to `opt/`:

   ```
   pack/dummy/opt/nerdtree/
   pack/dummy/opt/nerdtree-git-plugin/
   pack/dummy/opt/vim-devicons/
   ```
2. Add the following lines to your `vimrc` after any `syntax on` or `filetype on` line:

   ```
   packadd! nerdtree
   packadd! nerdtree-git-plugin
   packadd! vim-devicons
   ```
3. Start Vim:

   ```
   $ vim
   vim-devicons
   nerdtree-git-plugin
   nerdtree
   Press ENTER or type command to continue
   ```

   ***What?***

Well… I guess you could experiment with ordering, here, until you get the desired order but that reverse order looks like a bug to me.